# Creating a stack exchange site for Bonsai

Tags: discussion

I recently proposed a stack exchange site for bonsai trees.
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/107012/bonsai

As there are some really active bonsai forums out there I thought that this could be worth its own site. It will most likely never gain a big following but bonsai growers tend to be passionate about what they do so at least a passionate/active small following.

Do you guys think its viable or is it something better left as a part of the current Gardening & Landscaping site?

Comment: Whether or not the proposal makes it, I recommend that you keep asking/answering your own questions, like [this one](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/30886/). As you know, answered questions stay visible longer, drawing more views and answers. Also, questions in a tag can increase when there's an active question. Knowing there's someone with specific expertise makes people less afraid to ask questions.Tags are good for increasing traffic by searches, and showing related questions on the side of the page. Thanks for what you're bringing to the site!

Comment: Have been spending a little time on the this site and it seems I was overly ambitious with a site purely for bonsai. The Gardening & Landscaping site can benefit from more users and a bonsai site (if it ever made it) would only draw away from this community. Instead I will be asking and providing answers to bonsai related questions here. I look forward to helping build up the Gardening & Landscaping site!

Comment: Thus I also deleted my proposal, it is simply not the right time for a bonsai site.

Comment: There are a couple [unanswered bonsai](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bonsai?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50) questions you could look at if you're interested :)

Comment: Wow, that's a great answer you posted on [this](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/23735/tips-for-first-serissa-bonsai)! It probably would have been closed, and now it can really help the community, so, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I get where you're coming from, that this artistic subculture of horticulture is a widely practiced hobby, and specialized enough to have some difference from most other types of plant culture.

I also see that as of today, our [bonsai](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bonsai) tag contains only 93 questions that accumulated over the past 2083 days (over 5 1/2 years), out of 6950 total questions. I think the hard part of a proposal like that is building a user base. Even this site (up until this past year), was having a hard time with user activity, and this is a far more generalized topic with a much broader target audience.

I probably would have kept that subject included in the current site. But there's your proposal, and who knows, it may blow up with activity. As they say, though, hindsight is always 20/20, and we've seen that even the fairly broad subject of agriculture never got momentum.